# PHP inheritance methods or parent class name

Tags: php, oop, inheritance

I will try to explain my problem here by the code :

```
class A extends masterClass  
{
 function api()
 { 
  die(__CLASS__); 
 /* rest of the code here ... */}
}

class B extends A
{
 /* rest of the code here ... */
}

$obj = new B();
$obj->api(); // Should be "B"  (name of last child class)
```

Is there any 'best' solution for this ?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`static::class`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php#language.oop5.basic.class.class) or [`get_class($this)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-class.php) in place of `__CLASS__`.